# Upload file to server using SCRFTPRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7

Am uploading a file on FTP server in an iOS app using `SCRFTPRequest`.

An error occurs:

> Unable to create request(bad url?)

**CODE:**

```
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"rtf"];

SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://130.23.45.4/demo"]
                                              toUploadFile:filePath]; 

ftpRequest.username = @"user";

ftpRequest.password = @"pass";

ftpRequest.delegate = self;

[ftpRequest startRequest];

[ftpRequest startAsynchronous]
```

Comment: Have you checked your credentials?

Comment: yeah credentials  ok

Comment: Is `CFNetwork` framework added? Also remove `[ftpRequest startRequest];` and keep only `[ftpRequest startAsynchronous];`

Comment: yeah CFNetwork framework added.removing [ftpRequest startRequest]; now two error occur thats given below                                                                                        1.Error Occured .(due to SCRFTPRequestStatusError occured in did change status delegate)                                                                                                       2. Unable to create request(bad url?)